# How to detect if anything is overflowing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

There is more content in the divs than it can contain.

I want to hide all the text that isn't visible or is 'half-cut' horizontally as you can see.

Also I need to hide the last visable sentence or given number of letters and paste something like 'read more' instead of it on the end of visible part of the text.

The second part is easier I think. I've no idea about how to deal with first part.

Comment: you need to get font metrics, measure the width of the text, and check if it exceeds the width of the div.

Comment: I don't get it ... you'd like to hide something that is already not visible ? By the way i understand the second part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS.

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=ellipsis

```
.ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Or use [jQuery](http://tpgblog.com/2009/12/21/threedots-the-jquery-ellipsis-plugin/) plugin to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Following code may help you:

```
function isOverFlow(id){
    var elem = document.getElementById(id)
    if(elem.scrollWidth - jQuery(elem).width() > 0){
        return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```